VSCode extensions "GLSL Lint" and "glsl linter" don't find errors with .frag code even when there are problems
I'm new to coding and even newer to shader code. I've made a file, test.frag to test if my setup is working correctly. I have code snippets working but linting doesn't seem to work.
Code with errors where errors are not detected
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

void main(){
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0 0.3, 0.9, 1.0)
    
}

Here the errors are a missing ; character at the end of the line and a missing , comma character to separate the arguments of the vec4. The linters don't seem to find any errors though for some reason
I'm not getting any errors from the linters on startup, and i'm pretty sure i set up the validator-paths correctly
settings.json glsl linting validator paths
"glsl-linter.validatorPath": "D:\\D_Programfiles\\Bonus VSCode stuff\\glslang-master\\bin\\glslangValidator.exe",

"glsllint.glslangValidatorPath":"D:\\D_Programfiles\\Bonus VSCode stuff\\glslang-master\\bin\\glslangValidator.exe",

is it because i chose a separate drive? Maybe the spaces in the folder names? I don't know, but the extensions aren't reporting any errors? I'm also using the shadertoy extension to display the shader.
According to this video tutoriel the linter should be able to find an error in the code.
I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling VSCode, and it didn't help. I've also tried running the linters both separately and together, neither helped. I've also looked into some stackoverflow and reddit posts but i couldn't find this specific error (non error?), nor anything about it.
I've tried deleting every file and folder except the folder im running and the test.frag file.
Image of the test.frag file
I have not tried to configure either linter beyond setting the validation-path.

Did you save the file? It works fine for me, but I have to save to update the errors. Also, the extension called WebGL GLSL Editor contains the compiler, so you don't need to provide the path of the compiler (and it updates on type).

Oh, it seems that saving doesn't always work to find errors (although it often does, i just didn't try it until now), but closing and re-opening the file does. As for WebGL GLSL Editor, I've found it far more useful than the other linters, so i uninstalled them and switched to it, solving the problem entirely. Thanks for your comment!

Switching to a different linter solved the problem.
The linters i used would only work as intended when you save the file or close and re-open it.
Switching to the WebGL GLSL Editor extension solves the problem and provides live feedback on errors, and it doesn't require you to set a validation-path either
